# add directory to all incoming links that have wp-content

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to redirect all image paths from:

```
domain.com/wp-content/*
```

to:

```
domain.com/images/wp-content/*
```

This is not working for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /images/$1
```

Can someone help me adjust my rewrite?

Full htaccess file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lktoiy1zena7w48/htaccess%20copy?dl=0

Comment: What other directives do you have? There's nothing wrong with the rule you posted if that is the only rule you have. In what way is it "not working"? Do you get an error? Incorrect rewrite? What is it rewriting to? No rewrite at all? Where is the `.htaccess` file located? Is `/wp-content` a physical directory in the root? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: The way it is not working is that the rewritten URL does not have /images/ inserted.  The URL without /images/ is getting a 404 error.  I am attempting to retain backlinks, so the rewrite is to the new location of the image files.  htaccess is in the root.  Yes /wp-content is a physical location at domain.com/images/wp-content .  This is the one and only htaccess file.

Comment: Why are you using a RewriteCond to begin with, if you only have to check against the URL path? That can be done in the RewriteRule itself … `RewriteRule ^wp-content/(.*)$ /images/wp-content/$1`

Comment: That would be an _internal rewrite_ only though, if you want an external redirect, you need to add the `R` flag.

Comment: "What other directives do you have?" - Please update the question with your complete `.htaccess` file. It's likely you have a conflict with other directives.

Comment: Full htaccess file:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/lktoiy1zena7w48/htaccess%20copy?dl=0

Comment: Please edit your question to include your complete `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having looked at your entire `.htaccess` file...

You are missing an `L` (`last`) flag, so processing is continuing through the file and being rewritten by your Joomla front-controller, which will generate a 404 (by Joomla).

You need to write it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/(.*)$ /images/wp-content/$1 [L]
```

This is similar to the directive in your actual `.htaccess` file, except you had used the `R` (`redirect`) flag and not `L`. You presumably do not want to externally redirect the request.

As you have found, you don't need the additional `RewriteCond` (*condition*) directive.

The directive can be further shortened to:

```
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/.*) /images/$1 [L]
```

...to avoid repetition.